# AWS ec2 describe Instance not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

**aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-id "*****"**
This cli command works only for the region where you run this command, If i want to check Instance state of other location, unable to identify instance ID

Error: An error occurred (InvalidInstanceID.NotFound) when calling the DescribeInstanceStatus operation: The instance ID '***********' does not exist

Comment: Have you tried looking at the AWS documentation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to run the query in another region, simply define this when running the command:

For example, to run in us-west-2:

```
aws --region us-west-2 ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids <ids>
```